# Taglib array exception when setting Artist field

Tags: c#, taglib

I keep getting an array out of bounds exception with Taglib.tag.Performers in this function that edits ID3 data. I read elsewhere that clearing tag.performers[] can help (if null) but I still get the error sometimes.

Error message:

> "Index was outside the bounds of the array.Data:
>
> 'System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal' for test.mp3"

```
var fileArr = Directory.GetFiles(BasePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".mp3") || s.EndsWith(".m4a")).ToArray();

foreach (var file in fileArr)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
    string tagArtist = "";
    string tagTitle = "";
    string tempRegFilename = fileName;
    string title = "";

    //Apply to tag
    TagLib.File mp3tag = TagLib.File.Create(file);

    if (mp3tag.Tag.Title != null && mp3tag.Tag.Title.Length > 1)
    {
        title = mp3tag.Tag.Title;
    } 
    else
    {
        mp3tag.Tag.Title = String.Empty;
    }

    if (mp3tag.Tag.Performers[0].Length < 1 || mp3tag.Tag.Performers[0] == null)
    {
        mp3tag.Tag.Performers[0] = null;
        mp3tag.Tag.Performers = new[] { String.Empty };
        mp3tag.Save();
    }

    if (mp3tag.Tag.Performers[0].Length > 1)
    {
        string[] performers = mp3tag.Tag.Performers;
        if (title.Length > 2 && performers[0].Length > 1)
        {
            tagTitle = title;
            tagArtist = performers[0].ToString();
            Log.Info("ID3 Artist: " + "[" + tagArtist + "]");
            Log.Info("ID3 Title: " + "[" + tagTitle + "]");
            Log.Info("Tag data OK");
        }
    }
    //Get artist from filename
    if (mp3tag.Tag.Performers[0].Length < 1 || mp3tag.Tag.Performers == null)
    {
        mp3tag.Tag.Performers = new[] { String.Empty };
        string prevArtist = String.Empty;

        if (tempRegFilename.Contains("-"))
        {
            Log.Info("Artist data missing...");
            string[] words = tempRegFilename.Split('-');
            {
                words[0] = words[0].Trim();
                string perf = words[0];
                mp3tag.Tag.Performers = new[] { perf };
                Log.Info("Artists changed from \'" + prevArtist + "\' to " + "'" + perf + "'" + "\r\n");
                mp3tag.Save();
            }
        }
        mp3tag.Save();
    }
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error("TAG EXCEPTION: " + ex.Message + "Data: " + "'" + ex.Data + "'" + " for " + fileName + "\r\n" + ex.HelpLink);
}
```

Can anyone see what's wrong? I don't have much experience and could use the help. Thanks.

Comment: where are you declaring `fileArr` can you show all relevant code please

Comment: Code has been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be assuming in a number of places that `mp3Tag.Tag.Performers` will have at least one element in it. If it doesn't, then you'll get the exception that you mention whenever you try to access `mp3tag.Tag.Performers[0]`

It looks like you may be trying to catch that possibility with this code:

```
if (mp3tag.Tag.Performers[0].Length < 1 || mp3tag.Tag.Performers[0] == null)
{
    mp3tag.Tag.Performers[0] = null;
    mp3tag.Tag.Performers = new[] { String.Empty };
    mp3tag.Save();
}
```

But your logic is incorrect: you're getting the first element from the array (apparently a `string`) and checking *its* length, instead of checking the length of the array itself. Try this:

```
if (mp3tag.Tag.Performers.Length < 1 || mp3tag.Tag.Performers[0] == null)
{
    mp3tag.Tag.Performers = new[] { String.Empty };
    mp3tag.Save();
}
```

PS: It'll be much easier for you to see where your errors are if your log includes the stack trace of the exception, rather than just its message. I typically find it best to just use the `ToString()` on the exception itself.

Comment: Thanks, I made those changes but still getting the 'array out of bounds' error. Any suggestions?

Comment: @3lysium: Same issue exists on the next line. I updated my answer, but next time try debugging or looking at the stack trace first please.

Comment: I've not found a good way to debug a Windows Service other than to test within the app. Am now checking if the array has elements before looking at Performers[0] in each instance, and the problem is resolved. Thanks for the help much appreciated.

Comment: @3lysium: I'd strongly recommend breaking your program up into components that can be tested individually, without having to run the whole thing as a service. The code you provided could easily be placed in a standalone method that could be invoked from a test bed.  I'm glad I was able to help, though.

Comment: Yes, I have become painfully aware of this while building. I just can't be bothered to go back and unravel everything now that it's working. Will do this next time, thanks again.