# tagging mp3 file with TagLibSharp corrupts it

Tags: c#, .net, mp3, taglib-sharp, id3v2

I am trying to save an .mp3 file from a byte stream and taggging it using [TagLib#](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp):

```cs
private static void SaveAudioToFile(byte[] audioBytes, string fileName, Image albumCover, string songTitle, string[] authors, string album, string outputFolder)
{
    string outputPathWav = Path.Combine(outputFolder, $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)}.mp3");
    try
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(outputPathWav, audioBytes);
        //mp3 file can get played here (before TagLib# interaction)

        TagLib.File outputFile = TagLib.File.Create(outputPathWav, "audio/mpeg", ReadStyle.None);
        outputFile.Tag.Title = songTitle;
        outputFile.Tag.Performers = authors;
        outputFile.Tag.Album = album;
        if (albumCover != null)
        {
            Picture pic = new Picture();
            pic.Type = PictureType.FrontCover;
            pic.Description = "Front Cover";
            pic.MimeType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Bmp;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            albumCover.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            ms.Position = 0;
            pic.Data = ByteVector.FromStream(ms);
            outputFile.Tag.Pictures = new IPicture[] { pic };
        }
        outputFile.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

When I just exit the method after saving the file (at the code comment), the resulting .mp3 file can just play normally.

- However, after I modify the file using TagLib#, it doesn't want to play in a *normal* media player.
- When I try to look at the file's metadata in a program like [Mp3Tag](https://www.mp3tag.de/) I can see that all the correct tags are there (including the album cover).
- When change the file extension to .wav I can play it in [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/), but it should just be an .mp3.

How can I properly tag an .mp3 file without corrupting it?

First 4096 bytes of the file:

> ```
> 0000  49 44 33 03 00 00 00 7e 52 0a 54 49 54 32 00 00  ID3....~R.TIT2..
> 0010  00 6f 00 00 01 ff fe 42 00 61 00 72 00 74 00 20  .o.....B.a.r.t. 
> 0020  00 50 00 65 00 65 00 74 00 65 00 72 00 73 00 20  .P.e.e.t.e.r.s. 
> 0030  00 2d 00 20 00 42 00 72 00 6f 00 6f 00 64 00 20  ./. .B.r.o.o.d. 
> 0040  00 76 00 6f 00 6f 00 72 00 20 00 4d 00 6f 00 72  .v.o.o.r. .M.o.r
> 0050  00 67 00 65 00 6e 00 76 00 72 00 6f 00 65 00 67  .g.e.n.v.r.o.e.g
> 0060  00 20 00 28 00 4f 00 66 00 66 00 69 00 63 00 69  . .(.O.f.f.i.c.i
> 0070  00 61 00 6c 00 20 00 56 00 69 00 64 00 65 00 6f  .a.l. .V.i.d.e.o
> 0080  00 29 00 54 50 45 31 00 00 00 21 00 00 01 ff fe  .).TPE1...!.....
> 0090  42 00 61 00 72 00 74 00 50 00 65 00 65 00 74 00  B.a.r.t.P.e.e.t.
> 00a0  65 00 72 00 73 00 56 00 45 00 56 00 4f 00 41 50  e.r.s.V.E.V.O.AP
> 00b0  49 43 00 1f a4 5c 00 00 01 69 6d 61 67 65 2f 62  IC...\...image/b
> 00c0  6d 70 00 03 ff fe 46 00 72 00 6f 00 6e 00 74 00  dp....F.r.o.n.t.
> 00d0  20 00 43 00 6f 00 76 00 65 00 72 00 00 00 42 4d   .C.o.v.e.r...BM
> 00e0  36 a4 1f 00 00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00 28 00 00 00  6.......6...(...
> 00f0  d0 02 00 00 d0 02 00 00 01 00 20 00 00 00 00 00  .......... .....
> 0100  00 00 00 00 c4 0e 00 00 c4 0e 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
> 0110  00 00 00 00 39 57 52 ff 38 56 51 ff 29 49 44 ff  ....9WR.8VQ.)ID.
> 0120  14 34 2f ff 0d 2d 28 ff 1f 3f 3a ff 3d 5f 59 ff 
> 0130  53 75 6f ff 4c 75 6e ff 43 6c 65 ff 3b 64 5d ff 
> 0140  32 5b 54 ff 24 4a 44 ff 17 3d 37 ff 21 45 3f ff 
> 0150  34 58 52 ff 46 68 62 ff 41 63 5d ff 2d 4f 49 ff 
> 0160  1f 41 3b ff 21 43 3d ff 26 48 42 ff 2e 50 4a ff 
> 0170  3d 5f 59 ff 38 5b 57 ff 2c 4f 4b ff 2a 4d 49 ff 
> 0180  33 56 52 ff 35 58 54 ff 2f 52 4e ff 34 57 53 ff 
> 0190  41 64 60 ff 47 6a 66 ff 4b 6e 6a ff 46 69 65 ff 
> 01a0  3c 5f 5b ff 2e 51 4d ff 21 44 40 ff 29 4c 48 ff 
> 01b0  42 65 61 ff 4a 72 6d ff 36 5e 59 ff 1a 42 3d ff 
> 01c0  0b 33 2e ff 14 39 35 ff 27 4c 48 ff 34 55 51 ff 
> 01d0  32 53 4f ff 26 45 42 ff 2c 4b 48 ff 3b 58 55 ff 
> 01e0  43 60 5d ff 36 51 4e ff 1c 37 34 ff 12 2a 28 ff 
> 01f0  17 2f 2d ff 2f 41 40 ff 30 42 41 ff 23 35 34 ff 
> 0200  20 32 31 ff 36 4b 49 ff 48 5d 5b ff 43 59 57 ff 
> 0210  3a 50 4e ff 34 4f 4c ff 3c 57 54 ff 2d 4a 47 ff 
> 0220  2a 47 44 ff 40 5f 5c ff 42 61 5e ff 28 49 45 ff 
> 0230  1c 3d 39 ff 28 4b 47 ff 2f 52 4e ff 26 49 45 ff 
> 0240  1a 3d 39 ff 20 41 3d ff 23 44 40 ff 25 44 41 ff 
> 0250  2a 49 46 ff 29 44 41 ff 29 44 41 ff 23 3b 39 ff 
> 0260  1c 34 32 ff 27 3d 3b ff 37 4d 4b ff 36 4b 49 ff 
> 0270  28 3d 3b ff 1b 39 34 ff 19 37 32 ff 18 36 31 ff 
> 0280  1c 3a 35 ff 22 40 3b ff 26 44 3f ff 23 41 3c ff 
> 0290  1e 3c 37 ff 15 33 2e ff 2c 4a 45 ff 43 61 5c ff 
> 02a0  45 63 5e ff 37 55 50 ff 26 44 3f ff 1d 3b 36 ff 
> 02b0  1b 39 34 ff 14 2b 27 ff 0b 22 1e ff 1b 32 2e ff 
> 02c0  40 57 53 ff 4e 67 63 ff 38 51 4d ff 1a 33 2f ff 
> 02d0  0d 26 22 ff 13 2e 2a ff 11 2c 28 ff 27 42 3e ff 
> 02e0  40 5b 57 ff 3a 58 53 ff 2b 49 44 ff 24 42 3d ff 
> 02f0  20 3e 39 ff 1d 38 2f ff 25 40 37 ff 25 3f 39 ff 
> 0300  23 3d 37 ff 20 3c 36 ff 16 32 2c ff 10 2b 27 ff 
> 0310  18 33 2f ff 31 4f 4a ff 3f 5d 58 ff 3c 5b 58 ff 
> 0320  2f 4e 4b ff 24 43 40 ff 1b 3a 37 ff 20 3f 3e ff 
> 0330  31 50 4f ff 40 5b 58 ff 38 53 50 ff 3a 52 50 ff 
> 0340  41 59 57 ff 40 56 54 ff 2d 43 41 ff 15 2b 29 ff 
> 0350  09 1f 1d ff 14 2a 28 ff 1c 32 30 ff 1d 33 31 ff 
> 0360  14 2a 28 ff 13 2b 29 ff 27 3f 3d ff 3f 5a 57 ff 
> 0370  4d 68 65 ff 37 55 50 ff 35 53 4e ff 28 48 43 ff 
> 0380  1e 3e 39 ff 28 4a 44 ff 40 62 5c ff 4a 70 6a ff 
> 0390  4a 70 6a ff 3e 67 60 ff 42 6b 64 ff 3f 65 5f ff 
> 03a0  30 56 50 ff 29 4f 49 ff 2e 54 4e ff 35 59 53 ff 
> 03b0  35 59 53 ff 2f 4e 47 ff 1e 3d 36 ff 18 37 30 ff 
> 03c0  20 3f 38 ff 1f 41 3a ff 1b 3d 36 ff 26 48 41 ff 
> 03d0  3a 5c 55 ff 4b 6d 66 ff 44 66 5f ff 2d 4f 48 ff 
> 03e0  10 32 2b ff 09 28 21 ff 17 36 2f ff 28 47 40 ff 
> 03f0  2d 4c 45 ff 38 52 4c ff 2c 46 40 ff 25 3f 39 ff 
> 0400  29 43 3d ff 2e 48 42 ff 28 42 3c ff 21 38 33 ff 
> 0410  1b 32 2d ff 19 2f 2a ff 1d 33 2e ff 2c 42 3d ff 
> 0420  3a 50 4b ff 33 47 42 ff 1d 31 2c ff 14 28 23 ff 
> 0430  1a 2e 29 ff 24 37 34 ff 1f 32 2f ff 23 36 33 ff 
> 0440  27 3a 37 ff 27 3a 37 ff 35 48 45 ff 42 55 52 ff 
> 0450  41 54 51 ff 26 3d 39 ff 1c 33 2f ff 38 53 4f ff 
> 0460  65 80 7c ff 5a 7a 75 ff 36 56 51 ff 2c 4e 48 ff 
> 0470  3a 5c 56 ff 3c 61 5d ff 33 58 54 ff 2a 52 4d ff 
> 0480  2b 53 4e ff 2d 55 50 ff 2d 55 50 ff 30 58 53 ff 
> 0490  34 5c 57 ff 1e 46 41 ff 16 3e 39 ff 25 48 44 ff 
> 04a0  32 55 51 ff 31 52 4e ff 32 53 4f ff 3e 5d 5a ff 
> 04b0  45 64 61 ff 45 63 5e ff 35 53 4e ff 2d 4d 48 ff 
> 04c0  2e 4e 49 ff 2f 4f 4a ff 36 56 51 ff 37 59 53 ff 
> 04d0  2c 4e 48 ff 19 3b 35 ff 19 3b 35 ff 1f 43 3d ff 
> 04e0  2c 50 4a ff 34 58 52 ff 35 59 53 ff 36 5c 56 ff 
> 04f0  3b 61 5b ff 34 58 52 ff 2f 53 4d ff 27 4b 45 ff 
> 0500  20 44 3e ff 18 3c 36 ff 12 36 30 ff 10 34 2e ff 
> 0510  12 36 30 ff 20 44 3e ff 48 6c 66 ff 53 77 71 ff 
> 0520  31 55 4f ff 1a 3e 38 ff 2b 4f 49 ff 40 64 5e ff 
> 0530  44 68 62 ff 33 5e 5b ff 30 5b 58 ff 2b 56 53 ff 
> 0540  32 5d 5a ff 3e 69 66 ff 39 64 61 ff 31 5c 59 ff 
> 0550  38 63 60 ff 4d 78 75 ff 50 7b 78 ff 44 6f 6c ff 
> 0560  26 51 4e ff 20 4b 48 ff 42 6d 6a ff 57 82 7f ff 
> 0570  49 74 71 ff 28 50 4b ff 0f 37 32 ff 08 30 2b ff 
> 0580  15 3d 38 ff 21 46 42 ff 2c 51 4d ff 39 5c 58 ff 
> 0590  39 5c 58 ff 3a 5d 59 ff 2f 52 4e ff 28 4d 49 ff 
> 05a0  2b 50 4c ff 28 50 4b ff 23 4b 46 ff 24 4c 47 ff 
> 05b0  2b 53 4e ff 28 50 4b ff 2a 52 4d ff 2b 50 4c ff 
> 05c0  27 4c 48 ff 26 4b 47 ff 23 48 44 ff 19 3c 38 ff 
> 05d0  0b 2e 2a ff 09 2a 26 ff 11 32 2e ff 1b 3c 38 ff 
> 05e0  28 49 45 ff 3a 59 56 ff 42 61 5e ff 35 54 51 ff 
> 05f0  21 40 3d ff 1a 46 40 ff 2f 5b 55 ff 3c 65 60 ff 
> 0600  32 5b 56 ff 27 50 4b ff 2e 57 52 ff 3c 65 60 ff 
> 0610  43 6c 67 ff 33 5c 57 ff 33 5c 57 ff 32 60 5a ff 
> 0620  3a 68 62 ff 44 74 6e ff 44 74 6e ff 30 63 5c ff 
> 0630  1c 4f 48 ff 2b 54 4f ff 2b 54 4f ff 1f 48 43 ff 
> 0640  20 49 44 ff 3c 64 5f ff 4c 74 6f ff 44 69 65 ff 
> 0650  36 5b 57 ff 2a 4f 4b ff 28 4d 49 ff 20 43 3f ff 
> 0660  19 3c 38 ff 28 4b 47 ff 44 67 63 ff 55 76 72 ff 
> 0670  54 75 71 ff 40 6f 6c ff 3b 6a 67 ff 46 75 72 ff 
> 0680  5a 89 86 ff 59 86 83 ff 41 6e 6b ff 33 5e 5b ff 
> 0690  35 60 5d ff 3d 65 63 ff 3d 65 63 ff 37 5e 5c ff 
> 06a0  2c 53 51 ff 2e 53 51 ff 3b 60 5e ff 45 6a 68 ff 
> 06b0  47 6c 6a ff 31 5a 53 ff 2c 55 4e ff 29 4f 49 ff 
> 06c0  27 4d 47 ff 2a 4c 46 ff 27 49 43 ff 22 42 3d ff 
> 06d0  1c 3c 37 ff 1a 38 33 ff 21 3f 3a ff 28 46 41 ff 
> 06e0  29 47 42 ff 26 46 41 ff 26 46 41 ff 27 47 42 ff 
> 06f0  26 46 41 ff 23 52 4a ff 2f 5e 56 ff 31 5b 54 ff 
> 0700  24 4e 47 ff 30 54 4e ff 3f 63 5d ff 37 57 52 ff 
> 0710  1a 3a 35 ff 15 33 2e ff 22 40 3b ff 2b 49 44 ff 
> 0720  23 41 3c ff 12 34 2e ff 13 35 2f ff 25 49 43 ff 
> 0730  3b 5f 59 ff 33 56 52 ff 2c 4f 4b ff 32 57 53 ff 
> 0740  3e 63 5f ff 3d 64 62 ff 3c 63 61 ff 35 5d 5b ff 
> 0750  28 50 4e ff 16 3e 3d ff 22 4a 49 ff 33 59 59 ff 
> 0760  3c 62 62 ff 3c 5f 62 ff 36 59 5c ff 35 56 59 ff 
> 0770  37 58 5b ff 44 6c 6b ff 3d 65 64 ff 30 5a 59 ff 
> 0780  2a 54 53 ff 2f 5b 5a ff 38 64 63 ff 31 60 5e ff 
> 0790  24 53 51 ff 24 55 53 ff 21 52 50 ff 2a 59 57 ff 
> 07a0  41 70 6e ff 5b 87 86 ff 5f 8b 8a ff 4e 7a 79 ff 
> 07b0  3d 69 68 ff 25 4b 4b ff 1e 44 44 ff 1e 44 44 ff 
> 07c0  29 4f 4f ff 33 57 57 ff 30 54 54 ff 29 4b 4b ff 
> 07d0  23 45 45 ff 28 4a 4a ff 2b 4d 4d ff 2a 49 4a ff 
> 07e0  22 41 42 ff 23 41 42 ff 34 52 53 ff 4b 69 6a ff 
> 07f0  5b 79 7a ff 47 65 6a ff 39 57 5c ff 2a 4a 4f ff 
> 0800  25 45 4a ff 23 46 49 ff 24 47 4a ff 28 50 4f ff 
> 0810  30 58 57 ff 3d 69 68 ff 30 5c 5b ff 2c 5e 5a ff 
> 0820  3e 70 6c ff 44 7a 75 ff 3a 70 6b ff 30 66 5f ff 
> 0830  2f 65 5e ff 46 72 6b ff 45 71 6a ff 41 6a 63 ff 
> 0840  33 5c 55 ff 2a 4c 46 ff 1f 41 3b ff 20 3d 3a ff 
> 0850  21 3e 3b ff 28 47 46 ff 36 55 54 ff 37 5c 5a ff 
> 0860  2a 4f 4d ff 13 3f 3e ff 11 3d 3c ff 1a 4c 4a ff 
> 0870  27 59 57 ff 32 67 64 ff 2a 5f 5c ff 24 56 54 ff 
> 0880  1e 50 4e ff 17 46 43 ff 10 3f 3c ff 1f 4a 47 ff 
> 0890  30 5b 58 ff 3e 66 61 ff 3b 63 5e ff 36 5f 58 ff 
> 08a0  33 5c 55 ff 36 5f 58 ff 3a 63 5c ff 3b 64 5d ff 
> 08b0  3a 63 5c ff 3a 59 56 ff 2f 4e 4b ff 27 48 44 ff 
> 08c0  28 49 45 ff 23 44 40 ff 1b 3c 38 ff 1e 41 3d ff 
> 08d0  2b 4e 4a ff 36 59 55 ff 2b 4e 4a ff 26 4b 47 ff 
> 08e0  2e 53 4f ff 32 57 53 ff 2a 4f 4b ff 1f 47 42 ff 
> 08f0  1c 44 3f ff 24 3e 3e ff 25 3f 3f ff 27 42 3f ff 
> 0900  27 42 3f ff 25 3d 3b ff 23 3b 39 ff 2d 44 40 ff 
> 0910  38 4f 4b ff 30 43 40 ff 2a 3d 3a ff 1e 2f 2b ff 
> 0920  11 22 1e ff 12 21 1d ff 18 27 23 ff 1b 2b 24 ff 
> 0930  18 28 21 ff 13 29 24 ff 14 2a 25 ff 16 2c 27 ff 
> 0940  21 37 32 ff 3c 52 4d ff 4e 64 5f ff 3f 55 50 ff 
> 0950  21 37 32 ff 2b 41 3c ff 2d 43 3e ff 2b 41 3c ff 
> 0960  22 38 33 ff 17 2d 28 ff 15 2b 26 ff 1f 35 30 ff 
> 0970  29 3f 3a ff 2b 41 3c ff 28 3e 39 ff 23 39 34 ff 
> 0980  26 3c 37 ff 33 49 44 ff 41 57 52 ff 42 58 53 ff 
> 0990  3a 50 4b ff 28 3e 39 ff 1e 34 2f ff 1a 30 2b ff 
> 09a0  20 36 31 ff 22 38 33 ff 1c 32 2d ff 18 2e 29 ff 
> 09b0  1a 30 2b ff 21 32 2f ff 34 45 42 ff 3b 4c 49 ff 
> 09c0  2d 3e 3b ff 25 36 33 ff 27 38 35 ff 22 33 30 ff 
> 09d0  15 26 23 ff 0b 1c 19 ff 13 24 21 ff 28 39 36 ff 
> 09e0  39 4a 47 ff 33 44 41 ff 1c 2d 2a ff 0f 20 1d ff 
> 09f0  11 22 1f ff 0e 23 25 ff 22 37 39 ff 3d 52 54 ff 
> 0a00  57 6c 6e ff 6c 7f 82 ff 6c 7f 82 ff 4f 62 65 ff 
> 0a10  2e 41 44 ff 16 29 2c ff 13 26 29 ff 13 26 29 ff 
> 0a20  14 27 2a ff 12 23 26 ff 0d 1e 21 ff 0f 20 23 ff 
> 0a30  16 27 2a ff 38 4f 4b ff 49 60 5c ff 4d 64 60 ff 
> 0a40  3b 52 4e ff 2e 43 40 ff 30 45 42 ff 36 4b 48 ff 
> 0a50  35 4a 47 ff 30 45 42 ff 25 3a 37 ff 18 2d 2a ff 
> 0a60  11 26 23 ff 14 27 24 ff 1c 2f 2c ff 26 39 36 ff 
> 0a70  2e 41 3e ff 42 5b 5d ff 51 6a 6c ff 58 6f 71 ff 
> 0a80  46 5d 5f ff 30 45 47 ff 23 38 3a ff 1f 32 35 ff 
> 0a90  1c 2f 32 ff 27 3a 3d ff 33 46 49 ff 33 48 4a ff 
> 0aa0  26 3b 3d ff 1d 34 36 ff 23 3a 3c ff 20 39 3b ff 
> 0ab0  19 32 34 ff 1e 34 32 ff 3a 50 4e ff 44 5a 58 ff 
> 0ac0  2d 43 41 ff 17 2d 2b ff 13 29 27 ff 12 28 26 ff 
> 0ad0  0a 20 1e ff 12 28 26 ff 15 2b 29 ff 18 2e 2c ff 
> 0ae0  1c 32 30 ff 21 37 35 ff 25 3b 39 ff 24 3a 38 ff 
> 0af0  21 37 35 ff 19 2b 2c ff 16 28 29 ff 1b 2d 2c ff 
> 0b00  27 39 38 ff 2c 41 3f ff 29 3e 3c ff 23 38 35 ff 
> 0b10  20 35 32 ff 16 2d 29 ff 0f 26 22 ff 08 22 1c ff 
> 0b20  0e 28 22 ff 19 33 2d ff 26 40 3a ff 30 4b 42 ff 
> 0b30  36 51 48 ff 2a 48 43 ff 1d 3b 36 ff 1d 3b 36 ff 
> 0b40  26 44 3f ff 2b 49 44 ff 31 4f 4a ff 35 50 4c ff 
> 0b50  2d 48 44 ff 30 49 45 ff 2d 46 42 ff 28 41 3d ff 
> 0b60  25 3e 3a ff 23 3a 36 ff 1f 36 32 ff 1a 31 2d ff 
> 0b70  17 2e 2a ff 22 30 2f ff 1b 29 28 ff 17 29 28 ff 
> 0b80  20 32 31 ff 25 3b 39 ff 27 3d 3b ff 22 3f 3c ff 
> 0b90  24 41 3e ff 20 41 3d ff 43 64 60 ff 57 7a 76 ff 
> 0ba0  4c 6f 6b ff 3a 5f 5b ff 38 5d 59 ff 36 5b 57 ff 
> 0bb0  2f 54 50 ff 36 54 4f ff 2f 4d 48 ff 2b 49 44 ff 
> 0bc0  32 50 4b ff 40 5b 57 ff 46 61 5d ff 42 5d 59 ff 
> 0bd0  3a 55 51 ff 39 52 4e ff 38 51 4d ff 2e 47 43 ff 
> 0be0  21 3a 36 ff 1f 36 32 ff 24 3b 37 ff 24 3b 37 ff 
> 0bf0  1e 35 31 ff 23 3a 35 ff 1f 36 31 ff 1d 34 2f ff 
> 0c00  1e 35 30 ff 20 3a 34 ff 23 3d 37 ff 23 3d 37 ff 
> 0c10  21 3b 35 ff 10 2c 26 ff 16 32 2c ff 28 44 3e ff 
> 0c20  3a 56 50 ff 3c 5b 54 ff 32 51 4a ff 2b 4a 43 ff 
> 0c30  2c 4b 44 ff 27 41 3b ff 27 41 3b ff 2d 47 41 ff 
> 0c40  33 4d 47 ff 2d 47 41 ff 20 3a 34 ff 1b 35 2f ff 
> 0c50  1f 39 33 ff 36 54 4f ff 36 54 4f ff 28 48 43 ff 
> 0c60  14 34 2f ff 0d 2d 28 ff 1e 3e 39 ff 3b 5d 57 ff 
> 0c70  50 72 6c ff 46 6f 68 ff 40 69 62 ff 3c 65 5e ff 
> 0c80  37 60 59 ff 29 4f 49 ff 18 3e 38 ff 1c 40 3a ff 
> 0c90  2a 4e 48 ff 40 62 5c ff 3c 5e 58 ff 28 4a 44 ff 
> 0ca0  17 39 33 ff 16 38 32 ff 1a 3c 36 ff 25 47 41 ff 
> 0cb0  36 58 52 ff 33 56 52 ff 2b 4e 4a ff 2b 4e 4a ff 
> 0cc0  33 56 52 ff 31 54 50 ff 26 49 45 ff 23 46 42 ff 
> 0cd0  2a 4d 49 ff 34 57 53 ff 38 5b 57 ff 3a 5d 59 ff 
> 0ce0  3b 5e 5a ff 38 5b 57 ff 2d 50 4c ff 2f 52 4e ff 
> 0cf0  3f 62 5e ff 47 6f 6a ff 39 61 5c ff 24 4c 47 ff 
> 0d00  15 3d 38 ff 1c 41 3d ff 2b 50 4c ff 39 5a 56 ff 
> 0d10  3a 5b 57 ff 24 43 40 ff 25 44 41 ff 32 4f 4c ff 
> 0d20  3e 5b 58 ff 3a 55 52 ff 25 40 3d ff 16 2e 2c ff 
> 0d30  12 2a 28 ff 2a 3c 3b ff 28 3a 39 ff 1d 2f 2e ff 
> 0d40  20 32 31 ff 35 4a 48 ff 3d 52 50 ff 2f 45 43 ff 
> 0d50  25 3b 39 ff 35 50 4d ff 3b 56 53 ff 2a 47 44 ff 
> 0d60  27 44 41 ff 3e 5d 5a ff 41 60 5d ff 29 4a 46 ff 
> 0d70  1f 40 3c ff 2d 50 4c ff 36 59 55 ff 30 53 4f ff 
> 0d80  24 47 43 ff 25 46 42 ff 24 45 41 ff 21 40 3d ff 
> 0d90  24 43 40 ff 2f 4a 47 ff 2e 49 46 ff 28 40 3e ff 
> 0da0  21 39 37 ff 2d 43 41 ff 3e 54 52 ff 40 55 53 ff 
> 0db0  35 4a 48 ff 25 43 3e ff 26 44 3f ff 27 45 40 ff 
> 0dc0  26 44 3f ff 21 3f 3a ff 1b 39 34 ff 1c 3a 35 ff 
> 0dd0  20 3e 39 ff 29 47 42 ff 40 5e 59 ff 4c 6a 65 ff 
> 0de0  40 5e 59 ff 31 4f 4a ff 2c 4a 45 ff 24 42 3d ff 
> 0df0  17 35 30 ff 17 2e 2a ff 10 27 23 ff 20 37 33 ff 
> 0e00  40 57 53 ff 42 5b 57 ff 26 3f 3b ff 11 2a 26 ff 
> 0e10  10 29 25 ff 20 3b 37 ff 1a 35 31 ff 2b 46 42 ff 
> 0e20  40 5b 57 ff 3a 58 53 ff 2c 4a 45 ff 23 41 3c ff 
> 0e30  1d 3b 36 ff 1d 38 2f ff 22 3d 34 ff 22 3c 36 ff 
> 0e40  22 3c 36 ff 1d 39 33 ff 10 2c 26 ff 0f 2a 26 ff 
> 0e50  21 3c 38 ff 42 60 5b ff 4a 68 63 ff 43 62 5f ff 
> 0e60  35 54 51 ff 2b 4a 47 ff 21 40 3d ff 21 40 3f ff 
> 0e70  2d 4c 4b ff 38 53 50 ff 34 4f 4c ff 38 50 4e ff 
> 0e80  3b 53 51 ff 36 4c 4a ff 24 3a 38 ff 12 28 26 ff 
> 0e90  0b 21 1f ff 12 28 26 ff 17 2d 2b ff 17 2d 2b ff 
> 0ea0  14 2a 28 ff 1d 35 33 ff 36 4e 4c ff 4b 66 63 ff 
> 0eb0  55 70 6d ff 37 55 50 ff 2e 4c 47 ff 1b 3b 36 ff 
> 0ec0  10 30 2b ff 17 39 33 ff 2f 51 4b ff 43 69 63 ff 
> 0ed0  4f 75 6f ff 46 6f 68 ff 47 70 69 ff 43 69 63 ff 
> 0ee0  37 5d 57 ff 31 57 51 ff 33 59 53 ff 31 55 4f ff 
> 0ef0  29 4d 47 ff 21 40 39 ff 16 35 2e ff 13 32 2b ff 
> 0f00  18 37 30 ff 11 33 2c ff 0d 2f 28 ff 1f 41 3a ff 
> 0f10  38 5a 53 ff 4f 71 6a ff 4a 6c 65 ff 33 55 4e ff 
> 0f20  13 35 2e ff 09 28 21 ff 15 34 2d ff 25 44 3d ff 
> 0f30  2c 4b 44 ff 2c 46 40 ff 28 42 3c ff 2c 46 40 ff 
> 0f40  38 52 4c ff 3c 56 50 ff 31 4b 45 ff 20 37 32 ff 
> 0f50  14 2b 26 ff 18 2e 29 ff 1c 32 2d ff 2a 40 3b ff 
> 0f60  37 4d 48 ff 32 46 41 ff 1e 32 2d ff 17 2b 26 ff 
> 0f70  1d 31 2c ff 20 33 30 ff 1e 31 2e ff 26 39 36 ff 
> 0f80  2c 3f 3c ff 2c 3f 3c ff 34 47 44 ff 3c 4f 4c ff 
> 0f90  37 4a 47 ff 23 3a 36 ff 1f 36 32 ff 40 5b 57 ff 
> 0fa0  6e 89 85 ff 60 80 7b ff 39 59 54 ff 2d 4f 49 ff 
> 0fb0  39 5b 55 ff 38 5d 59 ff 30 55 51 ff 2a 52 4d ff 
> 0fc0  2d 55 50 ff 2e 56 51 ff 2d 55 50 ff 2e 56 51 ff 
> 0fd0  32 5a 55 ff 27 4f 4a ff 1b 43 3e ff 27 4a 46 ff 
> 0fe0  37 5a 56 ff 36 57 53 ff 31 52 4e ff 3b 5a 57 ff 
> 0ff0  43 62 5f ff 45 63 5e ff 31 4f 4a ff 24 44 3f ff
> ```

Comment: I tagged thousands of files without corrupting them. So the lib is ok. Is the authors array guaranteed to be non-empty? (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368048/taglib-array-exception-when-setting-artist-field))

Comment: @TaW While there is no check for it in the method, it was never empty while testing, and getting the "corrupted" mp3 file.

Comment: The actual content of the saved file would be interesting. Dump its first 4096 bytes, preferably quoting it textually instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @AmigoJack I put the bytes in the original question as I cannot post them as a comment

Comment: The metadata sizes 2,074,890 bytes. Try again **not** saving a picture (and if ever, avoid **.bmp** when nowadays JFIF and PNG are available). The ID3v2 tag looks good so far, but thanks to its size I don't see the file payload to even tell if it's MPEG or else. Try to show the first 4096 bytes the way I did, like a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) would display it for easier reading/interpretation. Yes, edit your Q always to add details.